# What is effective gravitational acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, terminology

Can someone explain to me what effective gravitational acceleration is from a kinetics perspective?

I understand what it is (the acceleration of gravitation felt by an object in another accelerating object, or, at least that is my basic understanding, if I am wrong here, do correct me) but I am not able to prove it to myself kinematically using force equations.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by a kinetics perspective? Isn't only dynamics involved?

Comment: @descheleschilder Ok, then explain it to me using purely dynamics...

Comment: I mean net gravitational acceleration that is felt by an object under some acceleration...

Comment: Do you mean by effective acceleration just "the "normal" gravitational acceleration? And if so, do you mean gravity caused by a mass is the same as the "artificial" caused by a, say(as usual) by an accelerating lift in empty space in which a person is present?

Comment: Like I said in my edited comment, say, a person in a lift accelerating upward?

Comment: @descheleschilder I guess that, so say you have a person going a up a lift with acceleration 'a', then the effective gravitational acceleration should be g+a. But I don't how this formula is derived, which is why I don't understand it...

Comment: Ah, now I mean what you mean by effective acceleration!

Comment: @descheleschilder In a classical mechanics book I am reading, it is defined as g(vector)+(-a(vector)) but I don't understand how that is derived...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **is** no way to derive this kinematically or dynamically. It's the result of the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle). Basically it says that if you find yourself in an accelerating elevator (through empty space), then the force you feel (you're pushed to the floor of the elevator) is the same as the force you feel standing still on a mass that causes the same acceleration as the acceleration of the elevator.
So if you standing in an upward accelerating (call this $\vec a$) elevator (which thus accelerates in the opposite direction as the acceleration caused by the earth, hence the minus sign in your equation), the acceleration (force) you feel will be exactly what you wrote:
$$\vec a_{effective}=\vec g + (-\vec a).$$

This **can't** be derived from another formula in dynamics. It's derived from the principle stated above.

Comment: I understand now, thank you!

Comment: Surely the implication of the equivalence principle is that inertial forces, like gravity, are in fact kinematic, not dynamic.

Comment: I think there is a lot of dynamics involved!